# using a graphical editor/ide to develop a project on Android running Termux

Tags: android, ide, termux

I'm developing on Android making use of Termux to simulate a linux box with webserver/database server etc. I can use Vi or Nano to edit a laravel/vuejs project inside that box. Now i found some pretty decent php/js supporting IDE's to run on Android but i can not use these IDE's to access files inside the Termux container since my device is not rooted. Is there anyway to do this? ...Connect the IDE to the laravel project inside the Termux Container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to answer my own question for the sake of completeness. I ran into 'code-server' which is more or less like Visual Studio code. In combination with Ubuntu on Termux this works perfectly and allows me to develop on my android tablet with full functionality.

https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/termux